# Run a function when post is deleted?

Tags: posts, functions, customization

Is it possible to run a function every time a post is deleted. The function has to be run when the post is deleted from the admin or by the wp_delete_post() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by [adding an action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) to the [before_delete_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/before_delete_post), [delete_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post), or [deleted_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/deleted_post) actions.

Comment: I was wondering how i could get the post id of the post being deleted. additionally, would this still work if multiple posts are deleted?

Comment: @shammer the post id is passed to your function, see the code sample on the `delete_post` page above. not sure how it behaves when multiple posts are deleted, I assume the action is triggered multiple times.